# trying map JSON dictionary child_items array if it exists

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a react Nav menu that reads from a Wordpress JSON menu dictionary file. It is working fine but only grabbing the first level nav items. Some of the Nav items have drop down menus which are not being displayed. In the JSON the primary NAV items may or may not have a key:  child_items, child_items is an array.

so first I check if key exists, then try to map new menu items.. my code is for the sub menu items is complete fail so far.. I can successfully grab first level items

Nav is in Components / headerComponent / header.js
main-menu.json is in public

here is a sanbox https://codesandbox.io/live/q625nmv

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
    Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

function Nav() {
    
    const [menus, setMenus] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("main-menu.json" ,{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    })
        
        .then(res => res.json())
    
        .then(json =>{
             setMenus(json.items)}
              )
        
       
         }, []);
        
    
    return (
        
        <nav>
            <ul>
                {Object.keys(menus).map((ky, idx)=> (
                 
                 <li id={idx} key={idx}>
                    <Link
                      to={{
                        pathname: menus[ky].slug,
                        state: {
                          pageId: menus[ky].object_id,
                        },
                      }}
                    >
                      {menus[ky].title}
                    </Link>

                        /* I added here to  */ 

                        {if(menus[ky].child_items) { /* do stuff */ 
                        <ul>
                        {menus[ky].child_items.map(child_items => (
                            <li key={child_items.ID}>
                                <Link
                                  to={{
                                    pathname: child_items.slug,
                                    state: {
                                      pageId: child_items.object_id,
                                    },
                                  }}
                                >
                                  {child_items.title}
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                    }}

                /* here for my sub nav items, all code outsid eof this works fine without my errors  */ 

                </li>
            ))}

            

            </ul>
        </nav>
  
    );
}
```

Comment: i don't know why but the link isn't showing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navbar

it renders menu with sub-menus. You need to do styling yourself.

```
function Nav() {
  const [menus, setMenus] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("main-menu.json", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())

      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        setMenus(json.items);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        {menus &&
          menus.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.ID}>
              <Link
                to={{
                  pathname: item.slug,
                  state: {
                    pageId: item.id
                  }
                }}
              >
                {item.title}
              </Link>
              {item.child_items &&
                item.child_items.map((childItem) => (
                  <ul>
                    <li key={childItem.ID}>
                      <Link
                        to={{
                          pathname: childItem.slug,
                          state: {
                            pageId: childItem.id
                          }
                        }}
                      >
                        {childItem.title}
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                ))}
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```